# How do I order file list in Dev Demon's Channel Files alpha by filename?

Tags: devdemon, channel-files

I need to order the files alphabetically by file name. How do I do this?

The "orderby" parameter docs are incomplete for Dev Demon's Channel Files.
Both Channel Files and Channel Images docs are also blank after...

> "The “order” parameter sets the display order of the images. Setting
>   options for this parameter include:

in the Parameters section of the docs. It just ends there after the colon.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `orderby="title"`.